# Adding です after 「また(some time/day)」

Tags: politeness, english-to-japanese

If I'm trying to say or write "See you on Tuesday" to someone politely, can I say

> また火曜日。

or is it better to say

> また火曜日**です**。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

また火曜日 does sound informal, but また火曜日です would mean "It's Tuesday again!"

Instead, you can say また火曜日に, which is politer and safe in everyday business conversations. If you need to be more respectful (eg, in an e-mail to someone outside your office), you can say また火曜日によろしくお願いします, etc.